# Div with background and some content has no height

Tags: html, css

I was making an HTML page that had a div with a image background and a link(s) inside it.

this is the css for background of the div:
HTML:

```
<div class="middle">
 <a href=# style="position:absolute; top: 0px; right:50px;"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.middle{
background:#fff url('login.jpg') no-repeat scroll center top;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;  
}
```

I have tried the "overflow:auto" step like in numerous questions of the same type but I haven't used any float like in the others, so I am confused.

What I want to do is that, the div should be of the background's size without explicitly giving the div a height of 'x'px.

Because for now, I have to constantly specify the div height for every page with image background just so it wont become a zero height div.

Comment: means u want to increase div height or what??

Comment: i just want the div to be the same height as the background image. So if the image is of 1000px height, then i want the div to be of the same size. If  I manaully find image size and apply that height for e.g.  

    <div style="height:1000px;"></div> 

then I get what I need, but I want to find a way so that the height is determined automatically via css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to make your div 100% height, all parent containers should have same height property set to 100%, otherwise your div won't have any height.
For some reason I think that what you want to achieve should be done in another way.

Comment: there was no other way to do it. Although setting all parent container's height to be 100% did the trick! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% I understand the question, but is this what you're looking for?

```
.middle{
background:#fff url('login.jpg') no-repeat scroll center top;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```